# Migrations - Laravel - PostgreSQL / MariaDB

Tags: laravel, postgresql, mariadb

Siempre he trabajado Laravel  usando como servidor de base de datos PostgreSQL. Sin embargo por requerimiento de un cliente, este desea utilizar MariaDB.

Con PostgreSQL acostumbraba a hacer mis migraciones de esta manera:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('profile_id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('address', 255);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('profiles', function ($table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }
```

Al ejecutar migrate hacia la migración sin problemas, pero ahora que estoy usando MariaDB me arroja un error de incongruencia de datos al realizar la relación del campo `id` de la tabla `users` Prestemos especial atención al tipo de dato que utiliza el  método `id()` de la clase `Blueprint` que leyendo la documentación de Laravel no es más que un alias del método `bigIncrements()` siendo este método un tipo de dato SQL:

> Auto-incrementing UNSIGNED BIGINT (primary key) equivalent column.

Como pueden ver en la tabla profiles la relación la estoy haciendo utilizando el método integer() que su tipo de dato es integer.

Ahora bien entiendo que me arroje error con MariaDB lo que no entiendo es por que no me arroja error con PostgreSQL. Revisé al documentación de PostgreSQL y conseguí lo siguiente.

> The bigint type may not function correctly on all platforms, since it relies on compiler support for eight-byte integers. On a machine without such support, bigint acts the same as integer (but still takes up eight bytes of storage). However, we are not aware of any reasonable platform where this is actually the case.

Por lo que entiendo es que motivado a que el tipo de dato Big Int no funciona bien en todas las plataformas puede comportarse como un tipo de dato integer.

Si alguien tiene confirmación de que la razón es la que deduzco le agradecería ayudarme a confirmar con una fuente más precisa, un log o algo por el estilo. Dado que sea  cierto, entonces debo estandarizar mi código colocando la clave foránea como `bigInteger()`.

Aprovecho además de preguntar porque en la ojeada que le di a la documentación de laravel no vi el método, si existe uno para crear un tipo de dato `integer` y no `big int` para un campo `Primary Key` `Auto Increment`.